# How to create an root element with several prefix:namespaces attributes in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new in XML and XSLT and I am trying to convert a XML in an ARXML. So far it works as I want, but I can't create the root element.

It should look like this:

```
<AUTOSAR xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0 AUTOSAR_4-2-1.xsd">
<AR-PACKAGES>
```

After the help here from @Martin Honnen and @JLRishe, my code looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:UML="omg.org/UML1.3" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0 AUTOSAR_4-2-1.xsd"
version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<AUTOSAR>
  <AR-PACKAGES>
    <xsl:element name="AR-PACKAGE">
    </xsl:element>
  </AR-PACKAGES>
</AUTOSAR>
```

So my result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AUTOSAR xmlns="http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:UML="omg.org/UML1.3" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<AR-PACKAGES>
  <AR-PACKAGE>
  </AR-PACKAGE>
</AR-PACKAGES>
```

So the problem here is, I don't want the `xmlns:UML="omg.org/UML1.3"` but i want the `xsi:schemaLocation="http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0 AUTOSAR_4-2-1.xsd"`
as attributes. Do you know how to change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases the easiest approach is to put the namespace declaration on the root element of the stylesheet and then to use literal result elements for the elements you want to create:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:UML="omg.org/UML1.3"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="UML">

<xsl:template match="/">
<AUTOSAR xsi:schemaLocation="http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0 AUTOSAR_4-2-1.xsd">
<AR-PACKAGES>
...
</AR-PACKAGES>
</AUTOSAR>
</xsl:template>
```

If you need to declare a namespace not needed in the result, use `exclude-result-prefixes`.

Comment: That works almost fine, but i also have another declaration in the stylesheet node 'xmlns:UML="omg.org/UML1.3"' which shouldn't appear in the rootnode.  I get the result: '<AUTOSAR xmlns="http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:UML="omg.org/UML1.3">'  So the xsi:schemaLocation=".." is missing but the xmlns:UML is there. It shouldnt be like that

Comment: I did not notice the `schemaLocation` attribute, it needs to be put on the root element of the result tree, not on the `xsl:stylesheet` element. As for preventing some namespace declarations from being put on result elements, you can use `exclude-result-prefixes="UML"` for that. I will edit my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Just use literal elements in your XSLT. This will preserve the namespace declarations:

```
<AUTOSAR xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
         xmlns="http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0 AUTOSAR_4-2-1.xsd">
    <AR-PACKAGES>
```